# Finite simple group $G$ containing no elements of order $5$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Assume that $G$ is a finite simple group and that $n_7(G)=8$ (where $n_7(G)$ is the number of Sylow $7$-subgroups). Prove that $G$ does not contain elements of order 5.

I state that since $G$ is finite, then: $|G|=7\cdot p_1^{n_1}\cdot\dots\cdot p_k^{n_k}$, where $p_1,\dots ,p_k$ are primes. For the sylow theorems I know that $7|n_7(G)-1$ and $n_7(G)|p_1^{n_1}\cdot\dots\cdot p_k^{n_k}$. Now suppose by contraddiction that $p_i=5$ for a certain $i\in\{1,\dots, k\}$. So since $G$ is simple, then $n_5(G)\neq 1$. 
At this point I don't know how to conclude the proof... Any ideas or hints?

Comment: An interesting related question is whether there are finite simple groups with no element of order 3.  There is one family of groups like this, but it's pretty rare, since lots of conditions (like having a dihedral Sylow subgroup) guarantee having an element of order 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $P \in {\rm Syl}_7(G)$, then $|G:N_G(P)|=8$ and $G$ embeds isomorphically ($G$ is simple!) in $A_8$. Also, since $7$ is the highest power of $7$ dividing $|A_8|=20160$, we have $P=\langle ( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7) \rangle$ or a conjugate.

Now it is not hard to see that the centralizer in $S_8$ of $P$ is $P$, and so $N_G(P)/P$ must be isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(P)$, which is cyclic of order $6$. So $|N_G(P)|$ is not divisible by $5$, and hence neither is $G$.

In fact there is a unique (up to isomorphism) simple group that satisfies these conditions, and that is ${\rm PSL}(2,7)$, which is defined naturally as a subgroup of $A_8$. In that example $|N_G(P)|=21$ and $|G|=168$.

Comment: +1 from me Derek!

Comment: @Derek Holt: just ingenious!